# How to execute a script within bash script, and not wait for it to complete?

Tags: bash

I am writing a script that runs occasionally and pulls jobs out of a mysql db.  When I do this, I run something like the following:

```
job="/tmp/blah.sh arg1 arg2 arg3"
eval $job
```

I need it to move on right after I run the eval, and not wait for the other script to complete though. What is an easy way to do that?  I tried

```
exec $job &
```

based on a thread I found here, but that did the opposite, it ran the script, and then just stalled after the "job" completed, and stopped my entire script.

EDIT:

The problem I am running in to with separating my args and script is that jobs has multiple lines and looks like:

```
/tmp/blah1.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
/tmp/blah2.sh null null null arg4
/tmp/blah3.sh arg1 null arg3 arg4
```

So currently I have it running just : eval $jobs : if there is only one line, and if there are multiples, I do a for loop and run each line.  What is the best way to run this in a for loop to pull out and separate the args and scripts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't use `eval`; instead, separate the command name from the arguments, then invoke the command in a normal fashion.

```
jobCmd="/tmp/blah.sh"
jobArguments=( "arg1" "arg2" "arg3" )

$jobCmd "${jobArguments[@]}" &
```

Comment: Always trust `chepner` for sound advise on BASH. +1

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `exec` - it replaces your running script with what you're invoking.

```
eval "$job" &
```

should do the trick.

Update:

- If the command must be executed via strings stored in variables, @chepner's approach is preferable to `eval`.
- Generally, though, any command can be sent to the background as is, just by appending `&`.
- Output from jobs run in the background can make the bash prompt seemingly disappear, possibly giving the mistaken appearance that something is still executing. In other words: the script that invoked the background tasks may have ended, but it may *appear* otherwise. Just press `Enter` to see if the bash prompt reappears.

Comment: Hmm.. It still seems to sit there and watch the stdout of script I pass it.